# tensorflow case error: Invalid argument: assertion failed: None of the conditions evaluated as True

Tags: python, tensorflow

Evaluation of this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def example(trans_type):
    trans_type = tf.Print(trans_type, [trans_type, tf.equal(trans_type, 2)], "trans_type")

    au = tf.case({tf.equal(trans_type, 0): lambda: tf.constant(0),
                  tf.equal(trans_type, 1): lambda: tf.constant(1),
                  tf.equal(trans_type, 2): lambda: tf.constant(2),
                  tf.equal(trans_type, 3): lambda: tf.constant(3),
                  tf.equal(trans_type, 4): lambda: tf.constant(4)
                  }, exclusive=True)

    return au


if __name__ == '__main__':

    tr_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([2])
    tr_data = tr_data.map(example)
    tr_data = tr_data.repeat().batch(1)

    it_x = tr_data.make_one_shot_iterator()

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(it_x.make_initializer(tr_data))
        r = sess.run(it_x.get_next())   # this one works however: r = sess.run(example(2))
        print(str(r))
```

results in following error:

```
2018-01-05 19:06:49.022920: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] trans_type[2][1]
2018-01-05 19:06:49.023131: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Invalid argument: assertion failed: [None of the conditions evaluated as True. Conditions: (Equal_1:0, Equal_2:0, Equal_3:0, Equal_4:0, Equal_5:0), Values:] [0 0 1 0 0]
 [[Node: case/If_0/Assert_1/AssertGuard/Assert = Assert[T=[DT_STRING, DT_BOOL], summarize=5](case/If_0/Assert_1/AssertGuard/Assert/Switch, case/If_0/Assert_1/AssertGuard/Assert/data_0, case/If_0/Assert_1/AssertGuard/Assert/Switch_1)]]
```

while the tf.Print statement clearly prints trans_type=2 and even shows that tf.equal evaluates to true. What's the problem here and more importantly - how to even debug it when tf.Print statement gives confusing results?

EDIT: changed to minimal example. It seems to be related to Dataset/iterators, just calling the method works fine.

Comment: Hm... I can't reproduce your case. What's `trans_type` originally?

Comment: well, that's a very good question, it's supposed to be an integer (scalar tensor?), but maybe there's a bug in code - that's why I use tf.Print for debug purposes and it prints that the value is 2 and that tf.equal(trans_type, 2) is 1 (that means True I guess?). What debug statements can I add there to find out more about the value of trans_type at that point of execution?

Comment: Do you mean `trans_type` is pointing to different nodes during execution? Usually I start with inspecting the tensors statically. But your case seems so odd... Can you make a MCVE that reveals the problem?

Comment: That itself may be a difficult task, but I'll try :) How's that even possible that tf.Print clearly shows that equals statement is true, while tf.case fails for the same statement?

Comment: I have a feeling there's dtype issue there. BTW, try to cast `tf.equal` to boolean. `tf.Print` is consistent with the next call, because there's `1` in the output. But somehow it's not converted to true.

Comment: @Maxim see updated question